# Greasemonkey script to add textbox to each row on existing site

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to figure out how to add a textbox to the last column of each row on a site. My Java/JQuery experience is quite limited and can't really wrap my head around this one.

I've pasted the code for one of the tables below.

I've tried getElementsByClassName, but not sure what to call.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
<tbody>
  <tr id="g_1_hKWlkSGU" class="tr-first stage-scheduled" style="cursor: pointer;" title="">
    <td class="cell_ib icons left">
      <span class="icons left">
        <span class="tomyga icon0">
        </span>
      </span>
      <div data-context="g:g_1_hKWlkSGU" class="mg_dropdown">
        <div class="mg_dropdown_wrapper">
          <span class="mg_dropdown_selected">-</span><span class="down_arrow">
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_ad time">19:45</td>
    <td class="cell_aa timer">
      <span>&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_ab team-home"><span class="padr">Barcelona</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_sa score">-</td>
    <td class="cell_ac team-away">
      <span class="padl">Celtic</span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_sb part-top">
      <span class="icons">
        <span class="live-centre">
        </span>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_ia icons">
      <span class="icons">
        <span class="tv icon1">
        </span>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_oq comparison" title="">
      <span class="icons" title="">
        <span class="slive icon0 xxx" title="This match will be available for LIVE betting!">
        </span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Java has nothing to do with this... I removed the tag. Java and JavaScript are two totally different languages.

Comment: What is the code you written that has not worked?

Comment: @epascarello I've gone through a few different attempts, the current one I have, which I'm not sure is even applicable, but I found it searching around a bit: var tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('soccer');
var cell = tbody.rows[0].cells[0];if (checkboxCell.length). Then I'm trying to figure out what I need to add to this, or if it's the wrong direction

Comment: Add the code to your question. I don't even see a "soccer" class name in the HTML provided.